# preg_replace Is it possible to replace everything in between two symbols?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've created a template system that replaces all variables starting and ending in '%%'. The problem is that preg replace sometimes replaces more than it should, here's an example:

```
<?php
    $str  = "100% text %everythingheregone% after text";
    $repl = "test";
    $patt = "/\%([^\]]+)\%/"; 
    $res  = preg_replace($patt, "", $str);
    echo $res;
?>
```

This outputs "100 after text", and it should output "100% text after text". Is there any solution to this? This is really bad because if there are CSS rules in the document, percentage signs are used and it ends up replacing all the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind to match all `%` symbols which was not present just after to a number.

```
(?<!\d)%([^%]*)\%
```

Then replace the matched strings with an empty string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iQ1eD9/1)

```
$str  = "100% text %everythingheregone% after text";
$repl = "test";
$patt = "/(?<!\d)%([^%]*)\%\s*/"; 
$res  = preg_replace($patt, "", $str);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
100% text after text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the [last-occurrence](/questions/tagged/last-occurrence) of two `%` symbols with this regex (and replace away), if that is what you are asking for:

```
/.*\K%[^%]+%/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/cO7zZ7)!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a faulty design and should not be worked around with some nifty regex. Think of using unique identifiers for the placeholders and only match from an allowed list of variable names.

Such as `$str  = "100% text {%_content_%}";`

And replace using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$res = str_replace("{%_content_%}", "test", $str);
```

or [strtr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for multiple replaces:

```
$replace_map = array(
"{%_content_%}" => "test",
"{%_foo_%}" => "bar",
);

$res = strtr($str, $replace_map);
```

Just an idea to target the core issue.

---

Till then to replace `%containing_word_characters%`

```
$res = preg_replace('~%\w+%~', "test", $str);
```

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/pY6jX3/1)

Comment: Great! It's incredible that you noticed the point about word characters. I thought about it for a while, then decided it probably wasn't the case.